# Regex for path name

Tags: ruby, regex

I want something that matches paths, such as those in a web URL without the domain name, or a Linux directory, something/like/this/and/allows-dashes

So in another word, the characters allowed are numbers, alphabets, dash, and slash.
First and last character can't be dash nor slash.

Best I can get is this

```
^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9(\/)(-)]*[a-z0-9]+$
```

but it fails at

```
a/b-c/d
```

Comment: `^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9/-]*[a-z0-9]+$` Why do you put a dash in parentheses?

Comment: You could also just use `^\w[\w\/\-]*\w$` . Of course this also means that your path must have at least 2 characters.

Comment: Not allowing a forward slash at the beginning or end seems odd to me, as the former is always valid, and the latter is if you're path is a directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your - as well. Please try the following

```
^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9(\/)(\-)]*[a-z0-9]+$
```